# SQL DB2 Select filtering values with Same Id and several rows

Tags: sql, select, db2

my problem looks like this. I have a large table with 1M+ records.
It looks something like this

```
ID STEP_ID
1    abc
1    dce
1    bbv
2    abc
2    ddb
3    bbv
4    asd
```

The thing is I want to write select query that would exclude all IDs if  step_id is equal to abc. So it would look like

```
ID STEP_ID
3    bbv
4    asd
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.step_id = 'abc')
```

For performance, consider an index on `(id, step_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.step_id = 'abc');
```

For performance, you want an index on `(id, step_id)` -- both columns, in that order.

If you cannot create an index, it might be faster to use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             sum(case when step_id = 'abc' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as num_abc
      from t
     ) t
where num_abc = 0;
```